# Using wdContentControlCheckBox in Word 2016

Tags: ms-word

I recorded a Word macro which inserts a checkbox.  The checkbox gets inserted, but the text does not.  Why?
fwiw I'm using Word 2016 on Windows 10.

```
    Sub CheckBox()
'
' CheckBox Macro
'
'
    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" z"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros from the Recorder are just a starting point. Here is your recording turned into a functioning macro:

```
Sub Checkbox()
  With Selection
    .Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    .Range.Text = " z"
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Sub CheckBox()
With Selection.Range
  .Text = " z"
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .ContentControls.Add wdContentControlCheckBox
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't try this one but thanks for answering.